# HTML canvas image map fill outside the area

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, imagemap

I have an image map and a canvas, I have it at the moment so the poly area fills with the colour, but I want it so everything outside of the poly fills, so that it appears that its lit up.

There will be more than one area on the image, I've just added one for now though.

The other thing is that on mouseout currently the fill disappears (which is correct) but it does so immediately, I want a fade so that it fades in and out on mouseover and mouseout.

Here is my html canvas/img map:

```
<canvas id="imgCanvas"></canvas> 
<center>
    <img src="/images/homepage.jpg" id="map-image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="" usemap="#homepage-image" /> 
    <map name="homepage-image"> 
        <area class="homepage-hover" onmouseover="myHover(this);" onmouseout="myLeave();" href="/about" shape="poly" coords="465, 766, 477, 710, 473, 605, 480, 490, 492, 455, 526, 432, 551, 430, 567, 379, 562, 334, 528, 237, 526, 208, 534, 178, 557, 142, 576, 122, 616, 108, 669, 94, 708, 106, 755, 124, 784, 146, 810, 200, 819, 247, 828, 300, 830, 352, 837, 409, 834, 443, 836, 457, 852, 467, 878, 486, 894, 520, 898, 564, 891, 612, 891, 663, 893, 706, 891, 766" /> 
    </map> 
</center>
```

Here is the js which draws the area onto the canvas:

```
window.onload = myInit();
var hdc;
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function drawPoly(coOrdStr)
{
    var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var i, n;
    n = mCoords.length;

    hdc.beginPath();
    hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);

    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i+1]);
    }
    hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);

    hdc.fill();
}

function myHover(element)
{
    var hoveredElement = element;
    var coordStr = element.getAttribute('coords');
    var areaType = element.getAttribute('shape');

    switch (areaType)
    {
        case 'polygon':
        case 'poly':
            drawPoly(coordStr);
            break;

        case 'rect':
            drawRect(coordStr);
    }
}

function myLeave()
{
     var canvas = byId('imgCanvas');
     hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function myInit()
{
    var img = byId('map-image');

    var x,y, w,h;

    // get it's position and width+height
    x = img.offsetLeft;
    y = img.offsetTop;
    w = img.clientWidth;
    h = img.clientHeight;

    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    var can = byId('imgCanvas');
    imgParent.appendChild(can);

    can.style.zIndex = 1;

    can.style.left = x+'px';
    can.style.top = y+'px';

    can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
    can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    hdc = can.getContext('2d');

    hdc.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)';
    hdc.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying tons of different ways it turns out using canvas' wasn't the way. Basically I got around this by switching images. I had tried this originally but using jquerys fadeIn/fadeOut and then changing the img src cause a jump and didn't have the smoothest dafe effect.

I now have images which I added opacity in photoshop to the area I wanted and then have them all set to opacity 0, except the initial img, then when I hover over the mapped area I used fadeIn to change the opacity to 1. This makes the transition nice and smooth and gives the desired effect - also because the mapping area is the same for each img I only need the single map.

If there is a way to do it via canvas' though I'd be interested, particularly how I can invert the area thats hovers so inside the area remains the same and around it fades to colour (with opacity). I've looked at countless map examples, none of which do what I am asking for.